# Is there any step by step guideline for new relic configuration for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, newrelic

Is there any step by step guideline on new relic configuration for MongoDB ?

Answer (score 0):

There is some information on MongoDB queries available through the Gem https://github.com/newrelic/rpm_contrib for ruby